# Add query parameter with out page refresh

Tags: jquery

I have url like

```
www.abc.com
```

When i click on a like or span i want url to look like `www.abc.com?text=abc` but don't want page to be refreshed. I am using jquery. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: You can achieve via ajax and change the url history to jQuery and also you can do if the url is (www.abc.com?text=abc) load the content according for that(because any one refresh).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try "hash",like this:

```
location.hash = 'xxxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn to work with Ajax, see here
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/